# How do I create a nested has_many or belongs_to relationship with DBIx::Class?

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

In my code I have three classes as follows: `Forum`, `Forum::Thread` and `Forum::Post`

What I want to do is create a belongs_to-relationship from the `Forum::Post` class to the `Forum` class and vice versa with a has_many, *preferably* without creating a custom function for it. (This is admittedly more of an intellectual exercise than a technical limitation or actual problem, but if it is possible, I would much like to know.)

The commented out lines contain my intention with the relationships, but in their current form, they fail to work. I've poked around in the documentation, but cannot find anything relevant to this specific case.

Any pointers?

The forum class:

```
package Schema::Result::Forum;

use Moose;
extends qw/DBIx::Class/;

__PACKAGE__->load_components (qw/Core/);
__PACKAGE__->table ('forum');

__PACKAGE__->add_columns (
    id => {
    is_auto_increment => 1,
    data_type         => 'integer',
  },
);

__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key ('id');

__PACKAGE__->has_many (threads => 'Schema::Result::Forum::Thread');
#This is the interesting line
#__PACKAGE__->has_many (posts => 'threads' => 'forums' );

1;
```

The thread class:

```
package Schema::Result::Forum::Thread;

use Moose;
extends qw/DBIx::Class/;

__PACKAGE__->load_components (qw/Core/);
__PACKAGE__->table ('forum_thread');
__PACKAGE__->add_columns (
  id => {
    is_auto_increment => 1,
    data_type         => 'integer',
  },
  forum => {
    data_type         => 'integer',
  },
);

__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key ('id');

__PACKAGE__->belongs_to (forum => 'Schema::Result::Forum');
__PACKAGE__->has_many (posts => 'Schema::Result::Forum::Post');

1;
```

The post class:

```
package Schema::Result::Forum::Post;

use Moose;

extends qw/DBIx::Class/;

__PACKAGE__->load_components (qw/Core/);

__PACKAGE__->table ('forum_post');

__PACKAGE__->add_columns (
  id => {
    is_auto_increment => 1,
    data_type         => 'integer',
  },
  thread => {
    data_type         => 'integer',
  },
);

__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key ('id');

__PACKAGE__->belongs_to (thread => 'Schema::Result::Forum::Thread');
#This is the other interesting line
#__PACKAGE__->belongs_to (forum => 'thread' => 'forum');

1;
```

**PS:** Additional columns to hold actual content were omitted for brevity.

Comment: What do you expect this nested relationship to do? What would `$post->forum` or `$forum->post` mean under these conditions? Can't you just use `$post->thread->forum` and `for my $thread ($forum->threads) { for my $post ($thread->posts) { } }` to do what you want?

Comment: @Phillip Potter: I'm a bit apprehensive of foreaching; what I in the end want to achieve with `$forum->posts` is *one* SQL query that fetches all the data. $post->forum is really just a shorthand for $post->thread->forum, so that's less interesting, I suppose.

Comment: I suggest you subscribe to the DBIx::Class mailing list and ask there. I'm not really sure how to do what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like nested relationships aren't possible. has_many takes a single foreign class, which has a foreign key to the calling class.

The good news is `$forum->threads->posts` returns a single `DBIx::Class::Resultset`. It is not translated into SQL until needed, so when you call `$forum->threads->posts->all()` or even something like `$forum->search_related('threads',{},{rows=>25})->posts->all()`, it only runs a single query.

If your goal is to have a $post->forum, it can always be a method: `sub forum{$_[0]->thread->forum}`

Answer (score 0):

What database and engine-type are you using? If you don't have foreign keys (like, for instance, with myisam tables in MySQL) then you'll have to provide the column names in your relationship statements.